# ArrayAdapter makes app crash

Tags: android, android-layout, nullpointerexception, android-arrayadapter

I have a custom array adapter that works on multiple 4.4.2 devices, but when I have tested with a honeycomb device or a emulator devices it makes my app crash.

Here is my implementation...
First I populate an array of strings with the a wifi connection name:

```
final ListView listview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview);
final String[] values = new String[10];
for (int j = 0; j < wList.size(); j++) {
    if (j < 10) 
        {
            values[j] = "SSID:    " + wList.get(j).SSID;
        }

    else {
            break;
        }
}
```

Then I add those values to an ArrayList...

```
final ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
                for (int i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
                    list.add(values[i]);
                }
```

I then use my custom adapter

```
final StableArrayAdapter adapter = new StableArrayAdapter(
                        TestWifiConnect.this,
                        R.layout.mytextview, list);

private class StableArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {

    HashMap<String, Integer> mIdMap = new HashMap<String, Integer>();

    public StableArrayAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId,
            List<String> objects) {
        super(context, textViewResourceId, objects);
        for (int i = 0; i < objects.size(); ++i) {
            mIdMap.put(objects.get(i), i);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        String item = getItem(position);
        return mIdMap.get(item);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasStableIds() {
        return true;
    }

}
```

When this is called I get this error

```
12-31 18:58:03.096: E/AndroidRuntime(5809): java.lang.NullPointerException
12-31 18:58:03.096: E/AndroidRuntime(5809): at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.createViewFromResource(ArrayAdapter.java:355)
12-31 18:58:03.096: E/AndroidRuntime(5809):     at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.getView(ArrayAdapter.java:323)
12-31 18:58:03.096: E/AndroidRuntime(5809):     at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:1467)
12-31 18:58:03.096: E/AndroidRuntime(5809):     at android.widget.ListView.measureHeightOfChildren(ListView.java:1216)
```

**So my question is, what am I doing wrong and why is this making my program crash?** I have researched this for a while now and some people point to making sure the list isn't null, but I'm not sure this is the problem since it works on some devices and not others. Thank you for any help.

Comment: Make sure you don't have null values in the objects List.

Comment: I just used dummy strings to populate the list instead of my actual values and that seems to be the problem. Do you know why android 4.4.2 can handle the null values and some other devices cannot?

Comment: Probably some changes in the ArrayAdapter class code. In most of the ArrayAdapter implementatiown the data that you pass to it can't hold null values because the adapter will call toString() on it if its isn't already a String object.

Comment: Hmm that's interesting. Okay, I've got it working now by checking to see if the values were null before adding them to my ArrayList. Thanks a lot!